# Keep new lines from array in div vs textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I have a bunch of text stored in an array.  When I output that in the console I see the new lines being kept.  If I output that into a textarea it works great and I have new lines, but I can't format the text with different colors (I need selections color coded based on keywords)

What I want to do is have the look of the text area with the new lines but output it to something like a `<div><p>array output here</p></div>` but keep the new lines.  Whatever I try it breaks them and  I see all the text together.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
//Works great but not format friendly as in colors
$('#textarea').val(myArray)

//format friendly colors but does not keep new lines
$('div[title^="divContainer"]').find('p').text(myArray);
```

any suggestions to have the best of both worlds?

Thanks

Comment: can you please add myArray value to your question too and better if you can create a snipeet.

Comment: @KiranDash Thank you, please see https://codepen.io/SS113/pen/GERmzO for a snippet of what  is happening.  Plus here is a photo of what  a sample array looks like: [myArray](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/f574ScCiDdXQVp_qaLAqde-ZHOEl4pFRbpDUUCKqhTDwjG4had9-2LaC3v7QHf79ZYbt8lC5mdqW=s600)  notice the "return" arrows in between the letters.  each one represents a new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through array and [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) `\n` with `<br>` and use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method

```js
var myArray = ["\nFirst test", "\n\nSec\nond test", "\nThird Test"],
  text = myArray.join(''),
  html = myArray.reduce((a, c) => a + c.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'),'');

$('#textarea').val(text);
$('div[title^="divContainer"] p').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div title="divContainer">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
<textarea disabled rows="10" cols="15" id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked beautifully!  I think my main issue was I kept using .`text()` and you used `.html()`.  None the less, I learned  something new, it's 4 AM and I can finally sleep!  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArray = ["hello","world"] ;
for (var i; i<myArray.length; i++)
{
   var result = $('div[title^="divContainer"]').find('p').text(myArray[i] + '\n');
   result.html(result.html().replace(/\n/g,'<br/>'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, while that does work with the different elements of the array.  In each element there is text with new lines.  The  textarea recognizes them but the `<p>` won't so  that's my bigger issue.

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript (I used `<br>` for the line breaks):

```js
var myArray = ["Hello, my name is Test1.",
"Hello I'm Test2.",
"Hello, I'm Test3."];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
 document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML =
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML + myArray[i] + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said above, the  problem is there are multiple line breaks within the string in each array element and I don't know how to break those if I don't use a textarea.  Here's a sample array that I'm working with.  Notice the return  arrows in between the lines: [myArray](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/f574ScCiDdXQVp_qaLAqde-ZHOEl4pFRbpDUUCKqhTDwjG4had9-2LaC3v7QHf79ZYbt8lC5mdqW=s600)